# Is it possible to remove an EF Core Database migration after the database is updated with the same

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In .NET EF core, Is it possible to remove/revert a Database migration after the database is updated by "*Update-database*" command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but only if it is the last migration or if you revert all  migrations after it.

To revert all migrations including the desired, use the [-Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#update-database) parameter of the same `Update-Database` command and pass the name/id of the migration **before** the desired (or special value `0` if it is the first)

```cs
Update-Database MigrationBeforeTheOneYouWantToRevert
```

For more info, see [Applying Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs) - [Command-line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs#command-line-tools) sections of the official EF Core documentation.