# Is there any way to revert an Ef Core - Database Migration after the database is updated by 'update-database' command

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to roll back a database migration after the database is updated by the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rollback to the last migration,

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:"NameOfSecondToLastMigration"
```

Comment: I have found the answer in another stackoverflow question below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265158/is-it-possible-to-remove-an-ef-core-database-migration-after-the-database-is-upd/68266243#68266243